# How to reset the view in MuseScore?

Tags: musescore

When using my TouchPad I sometimes do a move after which the whole sheet is gone (somewhere far out of the view). Maybe its the scroll function of the TouchPad, but I'm not sure. Then I need to zoom out or even close the file and reopen it to get back to the right view. Is there a more easy way to do that, maybe a shortcut? I tried the special zoom options like *page width*, *whole page*, but it didn't work. So

**How to reset the view in MuseScore?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my laptop I can press the "Home" or "End" key when not in note editing mode to scroll the first/last measure into view.

Comment: that's what I've been looking for